Adjoints to inclusion pseudofunctors from topoi to Cat
Let's consider the bicategories, LogTopos of elementary topoi, logical functors and natural transformations and GrTopos of Grothendieck topoi, geometric morphisms and natural transformations.
The standard free topoi arise from left-adjoints to functors from the 1-category part of LogTopos to category of graphs, if I understand correctly.
We have the obvious forgetful pseudofunctors from LogTopos/GrTopos, for GrTopos 1 for each direct/inverse image, into Cat. What is known about existence of left/right adjoints to these pseudofunctors?

By bifunctor, do you mean a https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor#pseudofunctor_between_strict_categories ?

This is a difficult question and you haven't got any answers yet, so I'll throw in some guesses to start the discussion: you may want the base 2-category to be Lex (categories with finite limits); then the free Grothdieck topos should be something like the Yoneda embedding and the free logical topos something like the von Neumann hierarchy; there probably aren't any right adjoints.

@PaulTaylor What do you mean by the "like the von Neumann hierarchy" part? My current guess is approaching it through, Dostál's Pseudoadjoint Functor Theorem. But that form gives a recognition of a pseudoadjoint pair of pseudofunctors rather than a recognition of left/right pseudoadjoint, so it will likely need some massaging to get into the correct form.

I hadn't heard of Dostál's work: maybe you could add a sentence and link about it. I was thinking in terms of a type theory with powersets, for which you would build a model by interating this construction: add a new object that classifies subobjects in the given category.  Osius's categorical set theory and my work built on that might help. Beware I am just guessing.

It's supposedly well-known that the 2-category of toposes and logical morphisms is 2-monadic over categories, which in particular involves a left adjoint answering part of your question. For instance you can see this claimed here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos I'm realizing I don't know a reference, though; Blackwell, Kelly, and Power don't get all the way there in their canonical paper on 2-monads.

@KevinCarlson that has another issue, it uses natural isos instead of transformations, my 2-category with logical functors in question is slightly different than the one usually considered in literature, where only natural isos tend to be considered.

Thinking about it now, I dont think I know of any place in literature that considers general transformations of logical functors, not only isos.

Right, sorry about my misreading; it's actually well-known that toposes are monadic over categories and natural isomorphisms between functors. It's apparently also known that, say, cartesian closed categories are not monadic over the full 2-category of categories you're looking for and I would guess that however that works also rules this out for toposes.

In one of the directions suggested by Paul Taylor in the comments, by Diaconescu's theorem the forgetful functor from Grothendieck toposes and inverse image functors to CAT (the category of large categories) has a partial left adjoint defined on all small categories, which sends a small category $C$ to the presheaf category $[(FC)^{\rm op},\rm Set]$, where $FC$ is the free category-with-finite-limits generated by $C$ (which is also small).  The latter can be constructed concretely, up to equivalence, as the closure of $C$ under finite limits in its co-presheaf category $[C,\rm Set]^{\rm op}$, so the whole thing is sort of a double Yoneda embedding.
And as Kevin Carlson said in the comments, the forgetful functor from elementary toposes, logical morphisms, and natural isomorphisms to the category of categories, functors, and natural isomorphisms has a left adjoint.
I doubt that any of the other adjoints you're wondering about exist.
